# PHP 8.2 Dynamic Properties Deprecated: how to use them anyway in a compatible way

Tags: php

In PHP 8.2, [Dynamic Properties are deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dynamic_properties), and will result in a fatal error from PHP 9 onwards.

Using *Dynamic Properties* on *Classes* running PHP 8.2 will lead to `PHP Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property is deprecated` **E_DEPRECATED** warnings.

Now, while this is generally a bad OO practice to have public/dynamic properties in a Class, *this question is **not** about the best OO practice* but instead, how to make actual code that uses Dynamic Properties compatible with PHP 8.2 onwards.

How to make actual codebases that make use of *Dynamic Properties* compatible with the new behaviour?

Comment: According to https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dynamic_properties you can put `#[AllowDynamicProperties]` on a class if you specifically want it to allow dynamic property creation. Is that useful for you? https://3v4l.org/YhvnO

Comment: @ADyson thank you for the hint, I never used [attributes](https://php.watch/articles/php-attributes) before. Will this RFC be also applied to PHP 8.2 onwards or is only a "sort of workaround" of this particular version? Also, do I have to apply this attribute on classes that _extend_ the base class that internally use dynamic setters, or has it to be verbosely set in every child class? Also, is it enough to put this attribute on magic `__set()` or globally on the _class_ itself?

Comment: I would assume it applies to all versions until it's deprecated and removed again. As for the rest, I don't know off the top of my head, you'd have to do a few simple experiments

Comment: @ADyson thank you again for the previous comment. I've tested the `#[AllowDynamicProperties]` attribute, and created a [github test project](https://github.com/mauriziofonte/php82-dynamic-properties-test) to showcase this particular feature. Anyway, I don't know where I'm getting this wrong, but it seems it does not work as expected. Do you mind having a look at that repo and help me understand where the problem is? Result of the test should be **no deprecation warnings** on `workingImplementation`, `extendedClass` and `usingTrait`, but that is not the case.

Comment: I don't have time to do that  but if you wanted to post a new question about it here and provide a [mre] of one particular issue you're experiencing, then the whole community can get involved. If I'm volunteering on stackoverflow at the time, I might also see it

Comment: @ADyson I've posted an answer to my question using your valuable input. What I was doing wrong is that it is necessary to use the fully-qualified `use \AllowDynamicProperties;` on namespaced classes. Thank you again for your contribution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson), the solution is to use the `#[AllowDynamicProperties]` *attribute* just above the *class definition*.

> Classes marked with #[AllowDynamicProperties] as well as their children can continue using dynamic properties without deprecation or removal.
>
> For classes that intentionally don't have a fixed set of properties, it's possible to either implement magic __get()/__set() or mark the class using the #[AllowDynamicProperties] attribute. Marking a class with #[AllowDynamicProperties] is fully backwards-compatible with earlier PHP versions, because prior to PHP 8.0 this would be interpreted as a comment, and the use non-existent classes as attributes is not an error.

This is a full example, as contained in [this github repository](https://github.com/mauriziofonte/php82-dynamic-properties-test) that I've created to test this feature on *Traits* and *Extended Classes*

```php
<?php
namespace App\Classes;

/**
 * Use the fully-qualified AllowDynamicProperties, otherwise the #[AllowDynamicProperties] attribute on "MyClass" WILL NOT WORK.
 */
use \AllowDynamicProperties;

#[AllowDynamicProperties]
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * Dynamic attributes will work with no deprecation warnings
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->first_name = 'George';
        $this->last_name = 'Orwell';
    }
}

class MyExtendedClass extends MyClass 
{
    /**
     * Even if "MyExtendedClass" is not using #[AllowDynamicProperties], it extends "MyClass", that is using it.
     * Dynamic attributes will work with no deprecation warnings
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Other noteworthy facts:

- If you're willing to use the `#[AllowDynamicProperties]` *attribute*
  in **non-namespaced contexts**, the fully-qualified `use \AllowDynamicProperties;` statement is not strictly needed (this extends the comment of [user706420](https://stackoverflow.com/users/706420/user706420))
- If you need a *quick and dirty* fix (for example, an old codebase) you can use the `class Foo extends \stdClass` as suggested by [Ale DC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10220740/ale-dc): dynamic properties will work as expected.

Comment: "use \AllowDynamicProperties;" is not needed.

Comment: @user706420 you comment is misleading, it leads to errors in namespaced contexts. I've added a specific test to demonstrate that the fully-qualified "use \AllowDynamicProperties;" is indeed needed in this cases: https://github.com/mauriziofonte/php82-dynamic-properties-test/blob/main/src/Classes/StackOverflowUser706420Test.php.
Your suggestion is true only when using #[AllowDynamicProperties] on non-namespaced scripts or framework structures (like here: https://github.com/mauriziofonte/php82-dynamic-properties-test/blob/main/showcase.php)

Comment: You can do `#[\AllowDynamicProperties]`

Answer (score 5):

replace this:

```php
class yourClassName {
```

for this:

```php
class yourClassName extends \stdClass {
```

Comment: I'd consider this as dirty hack, as it circumvents reasonable restrictions but is rather using less restrictive behavior that was added as also reasonable exception, considering objects in json

Comment: Here the link (which can be found on this page already) about the explanation: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dynamic_properties

Comment: Brilliant solution. Will this still work in PHP 9?

Answer (score 2):

When I was migrating to php8.2, this is what helped me

instead:

```php
class yourClass {
```

try this:

```php
#[AllowDynamicProperties]
class yourClass extends stdClass {
```

Comment: You don't need both attribute and extend class. Attribute should be good enough